# Swapping two values in opencv

Tags: opencv, swap

I am supposed to do DFT on two images and get their amplitudes and phases. Then I will have to swap their amplitudes and phases and do an inverse FT on it again and get the final image. The problem I am facing now is, how to swap the amplitude of image 1 to amplitude of image 2?
Thanks!

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: C++, I performed dft on the images and used carttopolar function to get the magnitude and phase values. I am now stuck on interchanging the values and performing the inverse dft. the function is cartToPolar(planes[0], planes[1], mag,pha); I was wondering if the identifiers mag and pha are standard ones to indicate magnitude and phase, or if I could use some other identifiers for the image two and then swap them for the polartocart function and perform IFT. Thanks!